# Displaying files from within an app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have my app setup to all `Open-in` with various document types. For example, user opens a PDF into my app and then rather than displaying it I have them select what folder they want to put it into and upload it to my server. I am taking the url, converting it to NSData and uploading that to my server (works great).

Then, when they want to view the file at a later time I am pulling the NSData from my server...this is where I am getting stuck. How do I take that NSData object and display the contents to the user from within my app?  Thank you.

Comment: what content you want to display?

Comment: store data in documnet directory for faster result

Comment: I don't want to store in document directory for an app specific reason. Say the initial file was a PDF, how do I get the data back to a PDF? I can do this with an Image just fine by using the convenience method `[UIImage alloc] initWithData:`

Answer (score 0):

If the server doesn't require any user/password challenge you can just do

```
NSURL*url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"your url goes here"];
NSData*data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Your can also have more control of your download using NSURLRequest and implementing the NSURLConnection class with it delegate methods

If you implement the NSURLRequest with a NSURLConnection you can challenge the user/password

For large content you can do the class method

```
+ sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:
```

For creating the pdf document from a NSData you can do:

```
CFDataRef myPDFData = (CFDataRef)data;
CGDataProviderRef provider= CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(myPDFData);
CGPDFDocumentRef pdf= CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(provider);
```

Where data is your received data

Comment: what if data is more in size then it would'nt affect application performance?

Comment: I am able to get the data from the server. So now I have `data` as your example above says...I am stuck with how to make `data` appear in a useful way.

Answer (score 0):

You either have to include view support for each type of document you are planning to support or hand over that task to another app which can do it for you using  UIDocumentInteractionController.

See [Document Interaction Programming Topics for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/PreviewingandOpeningItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010410-SW1) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Use a UIWebView to display NSData containing PDF

```
[self.webView loadData:data MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"utf-8"     baseURL:nil];
```

Web Views can display different Data.